# Search max value of column after individual operation on each value of that column using arrayformula or similar

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a Google Sheets with a column D with identifiers in a certain format (i.e. Y19_XXX):

```
Y19_234
Y19_213
Y19_814
Y19_215
Y19_817
...
```

Now I want to determine the highest value XXX in that column that is lower than 800 (here in this example thus 234).

I tried: `=MAXIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(RIGHT(D3:D300,3))),ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(RIGHT(D3:D300,3))),"<800")`, but the MAXIFS formula complaints it needs a range to operate, while I thought the `ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(RIGHT(D3:D300,3)))` formula resulted in a range.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY(SPLIT(A2:A, "_"), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 < 800 label max(Col2)''", 0), 
 {INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, "_"), , 2), A2:A}, 2, 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works, thanks a lot!